# Topic modelling - Assign a document with top 2 topics as category label - sklearn Latent Dirichlet Allocation

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, lda, topic-modeling

I am now going through LDA(Latent Dirichlet Allocation) Topic modelling method to help in extraction of topics from a set of documents. As from what I have understood from the link below, this is an unsupervised learning approach to categorize / label each of the documents with the extracted topics.

[Topic extraction with Non-negative Matrix Factorization and Latent Dirichlet Allocation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/topics_extraction_with_nmf_lda.html)

In the sample code given in that link, there is a function defined to get the top words associated with each of the topic identified.

```
sklearn.__version__
```

> Out[41]: '0.17'

```
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation 


def print_top_words(model, feature_names, n_top_words):
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        print("Topic #%d:" % topic_idx)
        print(" ".join([feature_names[i]
                        for i in topic.argsort()[:-n_top_words - 1:-1]]))
    print()

print("\nTopics in LDA model:")
tf_feature_names = tf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print_top_words(lda, tf_feature_names, n_top_words)
```

My Question is this. Is there **any component or matrix** of the built model LDA, from where we can get the **document-topic association** ?

For example, I need to find **top 2 topics associated with each doc as the document label / Category for that Doc**. Is there any component to find distribution of topics in a document, similar to the  `model.components_` for finding words distribution within a topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can compute the document-topic association using the transform(X) function of the LDA class.

On the example code, this would be:

```
doc_topic_distrib = lda.transform(tf)
```

with lda the fitted lda, and tf the input data you want to transform

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm

Comment: I'm a bit confused on this solution. I was hoping to get an output that shows the topics associated with each document. Something like this Document #1: Topic: [1, 2, 3]

Comment: What you get is the distribution of topics for each document. So each line corresponds to a document and each column to a topic. To get the result you want, what you can do is look at each line and get the column indices of the three largest values. The would give you the three most important topic per document.